# How to run any gguf model using transformers or any other library

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, cpu, huggingface-transformers, ctransformers

In ctransformers, I can only use certain supported model. How can I run any model like (mistral, zephyr) in the gguf format in CPU.

Answer (score 9):

`llama-cpp-python` is my personal choice, because it is easy to use and it is usually one of the first to support quantized versions of new models. To install it for CPU, just run `pip install llama-cpp-python`. Compiling for GPU is a little more involved, so I'll refrain from posting those instructions here since you asked specifically about CPU inference. I also recommend installing `huggingface_hub` (`pip install huggingface_hub`) to easily download models.

Once you have both `llama-cpp-python` and `huggingface_hub` installed, you can download and use a model (e.g. mixtral-8x7b-instruct-v0.1-gguf) like so:

```
## Imports
from huggingface_hub import hf_hub_download
from llama_cpp import Llama

## Download the GGUF model
model_name = "TheBloke/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1-GGUF"
model_file = "mixtral-8x7b-instruct-v0.1.Q4_K_M.gguf" # this is the specific model file we'll use in this example. It's a 4-bit quant, but other levels of quantization are available in the model repo if preferred
model_path = hf_hub_download(model_name, filename=model_file)

## Instantiate model from downloaded file
llm = Llama(
    model_path=model_path,
    n_ctx=16000,  # Context length to use
    n_threads=32,            # Number of CPU threads to use
    n_gpu_layers=0        # Number of model layers to offload to GPU
)

## Generation kwargs
generation_kwargs = {
    "max_tokens":20000,
    "stop":["</s>"],
    "echo":False, # Echo the prompt in the output
    "top_k":1 # This is essentially greedy decoding, since the model will always return the highest-probability token. Set this value > 1 for sampling decoding
}

## Run inference
prompt = "The meaning of life is "
res = llm(prompt, **generation_kwargs) # Res is a dictionary

## Unpack and the generated text from the LLM response dictionary and print it
print(res["choices"][0]["text"])
# res is short for result
```

Keep in mind that mixtral is a fairly large model for most laptops and requires ~25+ GB RAM, so if you need a smaller model, try using one like llama-13b-chat-gguf (`model_name="TheBloke/Llama-2-13B-chat-GGUF"; model_file="llama-2-13b-chat.Q4_K_M.gguf"`) or mistral-7b-openorca-gguf (`model_name="TheBloke/Mistral-7B-OpenOrca-GGUF"; model_file="mistral-7b-openorca.Q4_K_M.gguf"`).

Answer (score -1):

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer
import torch

# Replace 'model_name' with the name of the specific model you want to use
model_name = "model_name"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)

# Replace 'your_input_text' with the actual text you want to classify
input_text = "your_input_text"

# Tokenize the input text and convert it to tensor
inputs = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt", truncation=True, padding=True)

# Forward pass through the model
outputs = model(**inputs)

# Get the predicted class probabilities (or other relevant outputs)
logits = outputs.logits
probabilities = torch.nn.functional.softmax(logits, dim=1)

# Print the predicted class probabilities
print(probabilities)
```

Comment: This works for the normal unquantized model. I would like to run the gguf quantized model